# PHP session unset not working correctly

Tags: php, session

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "submit")
{   
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['Name'];
    $_SESSION['father_name'] = $_POST['Father_name'];
    $_SESSION['class'] = $_POST['Class'];
    $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['Address'];

}
if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && isset($_SESSION['father_name']) && isset($_SESSION['class']) && isset($_SESSION['address'])) 
{       
    echo $_SESSION['name'] . '<br>';
    echo $_SESSION['father_name'] . '<br>';
    echo $_SESSION['class'] . '<br>';
    echo $_SESSION['address'] . '<br>';
?>
<form method="post" name="secondform">
<button type="submit" name="clear" value="clear">clear</button> 
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['clear']))
    {
        session_unset();    
                session_unset();        

    }       
} 
else 
{ ?>
    <form method="post" name="myform">
        <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name"/>
        <input type="text" name="Father_name" placeholder="Father name"/>
        <input type="text" name="Class" placeholder="class"/>
        <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="address"/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">subbmit</button>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to click twice on the clear button. The loop is not working properly , session_unset not working properly. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: session_unset('value_to_be_remove') solves problem. to destroy entire session use session_destroy()

Comment: @PradeepSapkota You might want to read the documentation of [session_unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) again. It doesn't accept parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `session_unset()` part to the beginning of the page, right after `session_start()` (which always has to be first). Currently, after clicking on "Clear" you first echo the stored values, then you clear them. You don't really have to click it twice, loading the page again after clearing it would show that the session is empty. By moving the `session_unset()` up you clear them before you try to echo them.